# Klein model verifies hyperbolic geometry axioms?

Tags: proof-verification, model-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

I was recently reading about hyperbolic geometry and its models, so, I was wondering, do you know a book, an article, some classnotes, etc, wich contain a theorem or something that prove(s) that Klein model verifies hyperbolic geometry axioms? 
I know it's a model so it must verify the axioms but do you know where is written proof of this statement?

Comment: See any introductory textbook on hyperbolic geometry. Answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/275079/409) include a number of good reference.